# python での割り算

Tags: python

現在pythonを勉強しているものです。
下記のコードで、a/d, b/e, c/f を一つのリストに表示するにはどのようなコードを書けばよろしいですか。

```
total_s = [a, b, c]
total_z = [d, e, f]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんな風に書けます。

```
total_ratio = [s/z for s, z in zip(total_s, total_z)]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。